# ionic push notification app upload Error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am trying to implement push notification in ionic framework.

I was trying to upload the app on ionic's IO service but got this error insted,

```
C:\Users\orcilia49\Desktop\Push_Notification\Push>ionic upload
Uploading app....
There was an error trying to upload your app.
An error occurred uploading the build: The address you are trying to reach could not be found.
This could be your internet connection or the server itself is having issues.

The address you are trying to reach could not be found.
This could be your internet connection or the server itself is having issues. (CLI v1.7.15)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.15
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.2
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v6.2.0
```

Comment: My advice is to create another project and follow .. step-by-step documentation .. : http://docs.ionic.io/docs/io-install

Comment: try this tutorial https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications-guide/

Comment: i have use this already